# durandal mvc app authentication security

Tags: security, durandal, hottowel

I was able to successfully use  (code from index view)

```
  @if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    <div id="applicationHost">
        @Html.Partial("_splash")
    </div>

   @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor");
        if(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <script>
               window.userId = "@User.Identity.Name";
                console.log(window.userId);
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/App/durandal/amd/require.js" data-main="@Url.Content("~/App/main")"></script>

        } else {
            <!-- Remember to run the Durandal optimizer.exe to create the main-built.js  -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="~/App/main-built.js"></script>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

            <div id="login">
              @Html.Partial("Login")
            </div>

    }
```

to get the app to be initially forced to a login page, after logging in (using the standard mvc account controller and login form from the standard mvc4 app.

I then added a button to the footer to call the logout controller method (this function was added to shell.js and I have verified that it is called when the button is pressed)

```
 function logoff() {
            var token = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/LogOff",
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token },
                success: function (data) {
                    log("from success in logoff", data, false); //this shows up in the log


                    return true;
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    return false;
                }

            });
        }
```

I have debugged trhough the controller method and it successfully calls

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            try{
            WebSecurity.Logout();  //this call does not generate an error
            }   
            catch(Exception excp)
            {
                string msg = excp.Message;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("index", "HotTowel");
        }
```

the Index page is called and the user is no longer authenticated, but the
call to PartialView("Login") above does not modify the contents of the browser.

I don't understand why the Login partial view is not loaded in the browser.
I dont have any errors in the console and no other indication that something is wrong.

I have googled around and not found any examples of anyone extending the Hot Towel template to support authentication. (other than a couple things on SO about how to set the authentication token)
I took the first steps by simply giving the index view the ability to force the user to login before the durandal app is even loaded. This is working great.

what is the proper way to get this to work?
I have a sample using the Durnadal starter kit that shows this behavior.
I can provide to anyone who needs it.

Thhe javascript in shell.js returns html that appears to be the index page that the redirect indicates.
(working on trying to get the alert to show it all is problematic)

Working on getting a sample to skydrive etc

Comment: What does the "data" argument from your "success" callback show?

Comment: data element returned from the javascript below

Comment: zip your project up and then post it here.  There are a couple possible reasons it might not be working. Instead of routing to index after a signout.. redirect to the Login page.  Also check to see if Html.Render("Login") even works.

Comment: I was able to figur this out. As Evan probably suspected i was fouling up the redirect by calling loutgout with ajax. changed it to be a form post instead and all is working. the only real trick is how to get the verification token to be rendered in your form.. when i have a chance I will post the entire project

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sfubdmdct8wpz2a/BLkN6epx0V?m   as promised

Comment: downloaded your zip and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also:

```
        <div id="login">
          @Html.Partial("Login")
        </div>
```

Should be replaced with

```
        <div id="login">
          @Html.Partial("../Account/Login")
        </div>
```

This is so it can find the direct path to the login you wish to render. This should fix your problem. It is strange though you didn't get any errors at least a 404 on the "Login" page. I suspect some error handling was done and not displayed though.